# How are BLOBs stored in Azure?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, blob, azure-blob-storage

I did some research to compare file storage in SharePoint and file storage in Azure.
As far as I know, SP uses a SQL database to store everything. So in fact, when I put a BLOB into SP, it ends up in a SQL, as it is mentioned [here](http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/blob-or-not-blob). So there are some disadvantages of storing BLOBs in SP:

> Write operations are particularly problematic because the BLOB is written twice—first to the transaction log for transactional consistency then written to the appropriate table in the SQL content database.
>   Boiling down a lot of data, it’s pretty clear that files greater than 1MB perform better (reads and writes) when the BLOB is externalized,

Now I wonder if there are the same disadvantages with Azure BLOB Storage: Are they also end up inside a database? Do I have the same disadvantages?

Comment: `The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.`

Comment: This is off-topic, as it's not programming-related; it's an infrastructure question. Also, you're asking for disadvantages with Azure blobs (not BLOB - it's not an acronym), which is opinion-based. If you read the documentation on blob storage (both block blobs and page blobs), you'll be able to answer your own question easily, and also see that it has nothing to do with SQL Server.

Comment: @mikeb I don't see the relevance of your comment (independent of the OP's off-topic question).

Comment: @DavidMakogon - My point is that he is "fixing" an implementation optimization problem before he even has an implementation.

Comment: If you consider that everything is written to three storage stamps simultaneously then there are actually six writes - just to be a pedant - Do you have an actual question though? else I imagine this will be closed as off topic / too broad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short the answer is no. The BLOB is not stored in a SQL database in Azure Storage.
The paper below gives more insights to the internals of Azure Storage. Do read:
http://sigops.org/sosp/sosp11/current/2011-Cascais/printable/11-calder.pdf